error: invalid argument: File not found : /app/Resources/TestFiles/Happy.pdf in Docker Container .NET Test Project
I'm containerising a .NET Test Project using Docker Container, copying test resources (pdf) being used in tests. Resources are getting copied and I can see files inside container, but tests says:
error: invalid argument: File not found : /app/Resources/TestFiles/Happy.pdf
This is an existing test project working fine outside container and in azure pipelines.
Following code is responsible for loading file path during test:
string testFilesPath = Path.Combine("/app", "Resources", "TestFiles");
filePath = Path.Combine(testFilesPath, fileName);

Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

WORKDIR /app

COPY ["TestAutomation.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestAutomation.csproj"

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build -c Release

And docker compose:
services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.9
    container_name: selenium
    shm_size: 2g
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "7900:7900"  # NoVNC (web interface for viewing browser sessions)
    networks:
      - testsuit-network
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://selenium:4444/wd/hub/status" ]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 10s

  dotnet-tests:
    build:
      context: ./TestAutomation
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: dotnet-tests
    depends_on:
      selenium:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - testsuit-network
    environment:
      - SELENIUM_URL=http://selenium:4444/wd/hub
    entrypoint: [
      "dotnet", "test",
      "--logger:trx",
      "--filter", "DisplayName~Validate PDF file upload validation - Happy path scenario",
      "-l:console;verbosity=detailed"
    ]


networks:
  testsuit-network:
    driver: bridge

I tried following:

Directory and file are there inside container
File Permissions are OK
Other tests are passing, only tests require PDF upload are failing inside container while passing outside.


U can't upload/write a file to the container. You must use a volume in order to upload your PDF.

Do you mean volume mount? Files are actually getting copied there inside container

Yes,  volume mount.

I tried mounting volume, updated path to direct to mounted volume, but still it showing same message, file not found

Check upper/lower case in paths and filenames. Windows isn't case sensitive, but Linux is.

May I know how you mount the volume ? Like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/95785/web-app-docker-compose-persistent-storage ?

This is how i'm mounting volume inside docker compose file:
volumes:
- ./TestAutomation:/app

@HansKilian I have checked everything, path is correct, and in correct case sensitivity.
